# custom formula help needed: Counting a length along with the quantity of that specific length

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula

***Please forgive me if this sounds confusing

Hey guys I got hit with a task that is out of my comfort zone. 
I need a formula that looks up values from another table, and will look up each specific length and tell me how long of a length is needed along with the quantity of that specific length.

For example:

Column A contains the Part number(not really relevant to my question)

Column B contains the material number (100069,200015 etc)

Column C contains length of each specific part number(115, 115, 100, 100, 100, 95)

I have another table with a sum product formula (column B) that totals up the lengths needed for each material(column A is for Material number). In that table (column C) the desired output of the formula would be (length(number of part with that length)

ex: 115(2), 100(3), 95(1)

Meaning there is two parts with a length of 115, 3 parts with a length of 100 and 1 part with a length of 95.

Please any help would be appreciated, this seems like a more complex formula, or maybe I am just over thinking it.

[image: Original Data info]

As you see the column under the red arrow is what i want to add. Right now i have manually insert that information
[image: DESIRED INFO]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first table is called table1, with column headers Material and Length, you can use the following formula in your second table to pull the info you need:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Length],MATCH([@Material],Table1[Material],0)) & " (" & COUNTIF(Table1[Length],INDEX(Table1[Length],MATCH([@Material],Table1[Material],0)) )&")"
```

Comment: IF i was going to use this for multiple tables, would it be best to use this in a macro instead. There will be times tables will be added and we wont know their specific table names.

Comment: I thought this was the answer but it is giving me just the total and quantity of two. The data  i have it looking up includes more than one length some lengths have a quantity of 3 rather than just 2.